Cardinality of a set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ satisfying some integral equation
Let $S$ be the set of all non-negative continuous functions $f$ on $[0 ,1]$ satisfying
$\int _0 ^1 \sin ^2 (x)f(x)dx=\int _0 ^1 \cos ^2 (x)f(x)dx = \int _0 ^1 \sin (x) \cos (x)f(x)dx =1 $
Then $S$  is
(a) an uncountable set .
(b) a countably finite set.
(c) a finite and non-empty set.
(d) empty set .
My Idea :
$f$ is Reimann Integrable and
and it's trivial to derive $\int _0 ^1 f(x) dx=2     $
Now $\sin^2(x) $ is increasing on $[0, 1]$
Thus $f(x)\sin ^2 (x) < f(x)\sin(1) $ on [0, 1]
Hence Integrating both sides ,
$\int _0 ^1 \sin ^2 (x)f(x)dx  \le 2\sin(1)     $
which gives $2\sin(1) \ge 1$
How may I proceed ?

$\int_0^1(\cos x-\sin x)^2f(x)dx=0$ hence $S=\varnothing$.
Note that the continuity hypothesis can be dropped: if $f\ge0$ is such that $\int_0^1(\cos x-\sin x)^2f(x)dx=0$ then $f(x)$ for Lebesgue-almost every $x\in[0,1]$ hence $\int_0^1\sin^2x f(x)dx=0$.

Can you explain a further bit about the dropping off continuity ?
